# Search for a string pattern and put it in double quotes

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with a data in the format below. I am trying to find ways to generate a new file by searching for string starting `+` and put that string in double quotes. Also, if there is a `*` in the file, that is also to be put under double quotes in new file.

`file1`:

```
- local_policy:
     lp_from: +91
     lp_to: {066 121 111 198}
- local_policy:
     lp_from: *
     lp_to: *
```

I have tried sed, awk method, but no luck.

`output file`:

```
- local_policy:
     lp_from: "+91"
     lp_to: {066 121 111 198}
- local_policy:
     lp_from: "*"
     lp_to: "*"
```

Expected output is to put strings starting with `+` into double quotes and also to put `*` symbols in double quotes.

Comment: `sed  's/+[[:digit:]]*/"&"/;s/\*/"&"/' file.txt | tee newfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` and `tee` to print to `stdout` and save to a newfile.

```
sed 's/+[[:digit:]]\+/"&"/;s/\*/"&"/' file.txt | tee newfile.txt
```